# How to capture data at run time and store it in XML file in WPF?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, session

I am building an application in which the output XML file should look something like this.

```
<xml file>
<Session>
    <Machine name= XXX>
        <date = ####> 
            <Recorded Speech= XXXXXXXX>
                <Capture= picture.jpeg>
                </Capture>
            </Recorded Speech>
        </date>
    </Machine>
</Session>

<Session>
    <Machine name= XXX>
        <date = ####> 
            < Recorded Speech= XXXXXXXX>
                <Capture= picture.jpeg>
                </Capture>
            </Recorded Speech>
        </date>
    </Machine>
</Session>
</xml file>
```

and so on...

I am able to output all the data specified in the tags separately but not able to integrate them into a single XML file.
Also, I want to maintain the sessions. The data which is there in the XML is captured during run time.

I am trying to build this in WPF and using MVVM architecture.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to do them separately?  This should just be how to write an XML file.

Comment: Show some code, this is far too vague.

Comment: An XML document can only have a single root node. Are you trying to create multiple `<Session>` nodes at the root of the document?